# While messaging my windows phone automatically enter some number in front of the real number

Tags: messaging

Everything is written in the title...
When I message aboard it automatically enters 338 in front of the real number....
What should I do??

Comment: Did you mean "abroad" instead of "aboard"? If so, have you tried disabling International Assist?

Comment: Have you got the International assist turned on? Where's "home" for you?